# Append div to parentNode using exact coordinates on area map element

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns the parentNode and coordinates of an area map tag:

```
 <img src ="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets"
usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Javascript function:

```
var count = document.createTextNode("FooBar");
var dspan = document.createElement("span");
dspan.appendChild(count);

var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("area");

for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    console.log(hrefs[i].getAttribute('coords'));
    console.log(hrefs[i].parentNode);
    hrefs[i].getAttribute('href');
}
```

How can I attach the `dspan` element to the `hrefs[i]` parentNode using the `hrefs[i]` coordinates to position the `dspan` element. I need the new element to be placed anywhere within the area shape.

Comment: Please point out where exactly the span should go. And read through [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: you are not trying to determine coordinates on google maps right? because you would be able to locate coordinates via the url of gmaps: for example http://maps.google.com/maps?q=maps+49.062844,36.855354

Comment: No this is not for gmaps. Im trying to add this element to an image which has an area map placed upon it.